# Occurrence of symbol A found anywhere in L. LISP

Tags: count, lisp, common-lisp, find-occurrences

Here is my function

```
(defun freq (symbol_A List_L)
    (cond ((atom (car List_L)) 
        (cond ((eq (car List_L) symbol_A) t (+ 1 (freq symbol_A (cdr List_L))))
            (t 0))) 
    (T (freq symbol_A (cdr List_L))))
)
```

I am getting an error variable ATOM has no value. Here is what I am testing with

```
(freq  'c '((a c) c e)) --> 2
(freq  'f '(((s) o ) d)) --> 0
(freq  'f '(((f) f) f f)) --> 4
```

Can not understand where is my error.

I also tried this:

```
(defun freq (a L)
  (cond
   ((null L) 0)
   ((equal a (car L)) (+ 1 (freq a (cdr L))))
   (t (freq a (cdr L)))))
```

Comment: you really need to indent and format your code. Writing/reading unformatted Lisp code is really a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that `nil` is an atom, you can simply recurse over the `car` and `cdr` of each cons cell. When you hit an atom, add 1 if it matches or 0 if it doesn't.

```
(defun freq (sym tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      (if (eq sym tree) 1 0)
      (+ (freq sym (car tree)) (freq sym (cdr tree)))))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It would be better to know how to do it using primitive functions (without elt)

Comment: `elt` is just a variable here, you can call it however you want. It's not the standard function.

Comment: I've renamed it to `sym` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code.

**Indent and format your code**

First you need to format your code:

```
(defun freq (A L)
  (cond (atom (car L))             ; first clause
        (eq A (car (car L )))      ; second clause
        (T (+ 1 (freq A (cdr L)))) ; third clause
        (T (freq A (cdr L)))))     ; fourth clause
```

A useful `COND`:

```
(cond ((> i 0) :positive)
      ((< i 0) :negative)
      (t       :equal))
```

You have written something like:

```
(cond (> i 0) :positive
      (< i 0) :negative
      (t      :equal))
```

Here a Lisp interpreter would complain that `>` has no value. It's because it is used as a variable. `(> i 0)` is seen as the first clause and the test form is the variable `>`. Since `>` usually is not a variable, this is an error.

A compiler might even reject the whole form at compile time, since there are clauses which are not lists.

As you can see the parentheses around a clause are missing in your code.
Check the syntax of `cond`...

```
cond {clause}* => result*
```

A `cond` has zero or more clauses.

```
clause::= (test-form form*)
```

Each clause is a list (!!) starting with a test-form and followed by zero or more forms.

It makes also no sense to have two clause with `T` as the test form. The first one will always be take and the second one will always be ignored.

Comment: @MaksimKniazev:; about what? That ATOM is used as a variable, because you have a syntax error in your code?

Comment: yes I got the logic but I am lost on this parenthesis. Have you tried to fix it and run to see if for sure that's the problem?

Comment: @Maksim: I don't need to try that. It's obvious that your usage of COND is missing parentheses in the clauses and has a double T clause. You need to fix that.

Comment: I edited my answer, I am no longer getting an error, but am getting wrong output...

Comment: If I replace 1 for 2 then it will be correct, but I am not sure if that's the right way to do it...